# Is there an easy way to memoize (and flush) properties on Python at object level?

Tags: python, caching, memoization

I'm looking for a way to cache properties of an object. In my case, I suppose the object can change over the time, so the memoized value for the property should be flushable. In pure python, I want to have a behaviour like:

```py
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, text: str):
    self._text  = text
    self._bar = None

  def flush(self):
     self._bar = None

  def update_text(self, text: str):
     self._text = text 
     self.flush()

  @property
  def bar(self):
    if self._bar is None:
      print('Computing bar...')
      self._bar = f'Computation with "{self._text}".'
    return self._bar

foo1 = Foo('Dog')
foo2 = Foo('Fish')

print(foo1.bar)
# Computing bar...
# Computation with "Dog".

print(foo1.bar)
# Computation with "Dog".

print(foo2.bar)
# Computing bar...
# Computation with "Fish".

print(foo2.bar)
# Computation with "Fish".

foo1.update_text('Cat')

print(foo1.bar)
# Computing bar...
# Computation with "Cat".

print(foo1.bar)
# Computation with "Cat".

print(foo2.bar)
# Computation with "Fish".
```

Then, as you can see, I want to cache the `Foo.bar` property. My approach was to define a private property initialised as `None` and then assigned and flushed to obtain a memoized behaviour.

**Now, my question is if there is some method, library, approach or technique to obtain this behaviour without the need to have a private property (imagine you have tends of memoizable properties in the class).**

I was reading about the `@lru_cache()` decorator (and the newest `@cached_property`) from the Standard Library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), but I realised that the `cache_clear()` method removes the memoized values for all the instances of the class.

I was thinking that one possible solution could be to use immutable objects, but that solution is not as I want, because probably there will be situations in which I only want to flush one of the properties memoization.

Comment: Properties are almost always built on private attributes.

Comment: Yes, but when I discovered the `@cached_property` decorator I realised me that it would be really interesting to get the same behaviour without the needed of private attributes. :)

Comment: Why `cached_property` doesn't satisfy your needs?

Comment: Also, are we talking about the same `cached_property` implementation? I found one here: https://pypi.org/project/cached-property/

Comment: As I mentioned in my question `@cached_property` (defined in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) works at function level and it's shared between all the instances of the class, so if I flush it for one of them, then is flushed for all the objects. For a sample, when you flush you need to do something like `Foo.bar.clear_cache()` (at class level).

Comment: Nevertheless, the implementation you said (https://pypi.org/project/cached-property/) looks like a good solution for the escenario I described in the question.

Comment: You said that _it's shared between all the instances of the class_. But I am not sure if it is true. Documentation says _cached as a normal attribute for the life of the instance_. Looks like it is not shared.

Comment: Maybe I explained me bad. What I wanted to say is that the cacheable behaviour and the flush point is shared. I mean, the caching system works using the arguments as key. In the propery case, the argument is `self` but the cache registry is shared between all the instances of the class.

Comment: Nevertheless, your recommendation to use pypi.org/project/cached-property works as expected. The cache is at instance and method level, so this is the correct answer for me. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to @sanyash discussion on question comments.**

There is a `cached_property` package (https://pypi.org/project/cached-property/) that provides the requested behaviour. The example using `cached_property` is as follows:

```py
from cached_property import cached_property


class Foo:

    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self._text = text

    def flush(self):
        del self.__dict__['bar']

    def update_text(self, text: str):
        self._text = text
        self.flush()

    @cached_property
    def bar(self):
        print('Computing bar...')
        return f'Computation with "{self._text}".'


foo1 = Foo('Dog')
foo2 = Foo('Fish')

print(foo1.bar)
# Computing bar...
# Computation with "Dog".

print(foo1.bar)
# Computation with "Dog".

print(foo2.bar)
# Computing bar...
# Computation with "Fish".

print(foo2.bar)
# Computation with "Fish".

foo1.update_text('Cat')

print(foo1.bar)
# Computing bar...
# Computation with "Cat".

print(foo1.bar)
# Computation with "Cat".

print(foo2.bar)
# Computation with "Fish".
```

Answer (score 0):

`cached_property` is the perfect solution to cache properties.

If you have similar concern about functions, [methodtools](https://pypi.org/project/methodtools/) works for each instances.

```py
import methodtools

class Foo:
  @methodtools.lru_cache(maxsize=128)
  def bar(self, a, b, c):
    return something_using_parameters
```